# call multiple APIs synchronously and show results immediately

Tags: json, api, jquery, jquery-mobile

Am working in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap.
Currently am facing a Big issue. When I click a button and at that time its calls multiple APIs one by one and get results one by one. But in result page its shows only after getting all the Results of all API.

In My Application When I Submit the Button and It return a JSON which contains the list of Different APIs to Call

[image]

Then We call each API **asynchronously**.

**We get all the result one by one. And Result is showing only after get all the results.**
[image]

**Then My Question is is there any way to shows the result page when I get First API Result and call all other API at that same time when Data shown in Result page in background?**

Currently for shows the result Page it takes more than 30 seconds time. But We need to shows the result page when we get first API result. We get result as JSON Format.

Anybody please can help Me :(
i lost my 1 week for resolve this issue !!

Comment: If you put the results into the DOM one-by-one, they should show up immediately. Or do you send from inside a form?

Comment: We are not send from inside a form

Comment: Can you share the code which is doing the ajax request and updating the DOM?

Comment: May be you set async:false in your ajax request. Change that to async:true or remove that line, by default async is set to true.

Comment: @abhidsm We Get result one by one. but its only append to HTML after getting all the Result from all the APIs

Comment: @abhidsm when we set async:true ; then second part API calling is not working !

Comment: Use async:true only in the second part API calling

Comment: Yes.. as your suggestion. but its not give any result ! :(

Comment: Actually your problem is when first api complete html must update and go for next api and update html is it ?,Use any  semantic templates

Comment: Yes Arjun.. thats my issue.can plz share ny example?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of HTML template solutions are available jQuery Templates, Underscore, and Mustache etc, better to use [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) i think that solves your problem. its better to use any templates if you are working on so many DOM manipulation in your projects.
Eg:

HTML Template

```
<h1>{{header}}</h1>
{{#bug}}
{{/bug}}

{{#items}}
  {{#first}}
    <li><strong>{{name}}</strong></li>
  {{/first}}
  {{#link}}
    <li><a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/link}}
{{/items}}

{{#empty}}
  <p>The list is empty.</p>
{{/empty}}
```

JSON DATA

```
{
  "header": "Colors",
  "items": [
      {"name": "red", "first": true, "url": "#Red"},
      {"name": "green", "link": true, "url": "#Green"},
      {"name": "blue", "link": true, "url": "#Blue"}
  ],
  "empty": false
}
```

Out put HTML

```
<h1>Colors</h1>
<li><strong>red</strong></li>
<li><a href="#Green">green</a></li>
<li><a href="#Blue">blue</a></li>
```